# Should I make the `GetObjectData` method virtual explicitly in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, interface, deserialization, virtual

Should I make the `GetObjectData` method virtual explicitly in C#?

In the **CLR via C#** book I met the following excerpt:

> If your derived type doesn’t have any additional fields in it and therefore has no special
>   serialization/deserialization needs, then you do not have to implement `ISerializable` at all. **Like all
>   interface members, `GetObjectData` is virtual** and will be called to properly serialize the object. In
>   addition, the formatter treats the special constructor as “virtualized.” That is, during deserialization, the formatter will check the type that it is trying to instantiate. If that type doesn’t offer the special constructor, then the formatter will scan base classes until it finds one that implements the special constructor.

As I know ([source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d43cba02-5f3b-4000-a7a1-89607260cce8/are-c-interface-members-virtual?forum=csharplanguage)), the interface methods are not virtual by default. So, why would we say the following **Like all interface members, `GetObjectData` is virtual**? Does it mean that when there is any interface method related to serialization/deserialization, then we should make it virtual or does it mean something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the `GetObjectData` method on that interface is virtual. By default, all methods on C# interfaces are virtual.

For example, if there's an interface:

```
interface IMyInterface
{ 
    void MyMethod();
}
```

The IL of the interface:

```
.class interface nested private auto ansi abstract IMyInterface
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual 
        instance void MyMethod () cil managed 
    {
    } // end of method IMyInterface::MyMethod

} // end of class IMyInterface
```

`MyMethod` is by default marked as `virtual`.

It doesn't mean that when the interface is implemented by a class, the class method will still be virtual. You will have to explicitly add `virtual` keyword to method on your implementation class to make it virtual if the method needs to be virtual.

**UPDATE**

IL of default implementation of `MyMethod`:

```
.method public final hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance void MyMethod () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 2 (0x2)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ret
    } // end of method MyClass::MyMethod
```

The implementation is by default `final` and `virtual`, meaning that the method cannot be overridden in derived classes by default. Adding `virtual` keyword to the implementation method removes `final`.

Comment: Oh. Thank you. That part about the interface methods being virtual before being implemented and becoming non-virtual (by default) when implemented is really confusing. :)

Comment: Hm. The author makes the bolded in the excerpt statement in such a manner as if the methods continue to be virtual (by default) even after being implemented. And this confuses me even more. Maybe you happen to understand what is  exactly conveyed in the statement? :)

Comment: Well... it is true as well. The method once implemented, it's by default `final` and `virtual`. If you interested in seeing that, you could use ILSpy to decompile some C# code :)